# sort elasticsearch data within array

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have data in elasticsearch

```
"id": "edff12sd3",
"desc": "elastic_data"
"main_array": [
{
"id": "2308",
"name": "Grey Area",
"location": {
  "lat": 28.5696577,
  "lon": 77.3229933
 }
},
{ 
"id": "2274",
"name": "Tribute to The Beatles by Atul Ahuja- Live Music",
"location": {
  "lat": 29.5696577,
  "lon": 77.3229933
}
},
{ 
"id": "2275",
"name": "Tribute to Music",
"location": {
  "lat": 29.9696577,
  "lon": 77.3229933
}
}
```

Now i have to sort this array object by distance
I had tried like this

```
{
"query": {
"filtered": {
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "elastic_data",
      "fields": [
        "desc"
      ]
    }
  }
}
},"sort": [
      {
    "_geo_distance": {
      "main_array.location": {
        "lat": 28.613939,
        "lon": 77.209021
      }
      },
      "order": "asc",
      "unit": "km"
    }
      }
    ]
}
```

i have tried to sort the all objects within main_array by distance but its doesn't works, It shows me overall distance not for individual data present in main_array.

please help me out. thanks